# Access subform keeps adding new extra empty record into table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having issue with access form (Contains combo boxes) and subform (display data from form combo boxes combination). I have 3 combo box on form and a report button. When I click on report button, the sub form will show report data based on combo boxes values.

It shows right data based on user selection on combo boxes but it gives me an empty record also and add that record into table also. How to prevent adding an empty record into table?

My Code:--

```
Private Sub Department_AfterUpdate()

dsSQL = "A select statment"
Me![Student].RowSource = ""
Me![Student].RowSource = dsSQL

dcSQL = "A select statment"
Me![Course].RowSource = ""
Me![Course].RowSource = dcSQL

End Sub


Private Sub Student_AfterUpdate()
 sSQL = "A Select statement"     
 Me![Course].RowSource = ""
 Me![Course].RowSource = sSQL

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: If you go to the Data tab under Form Properties and set Data Entry Mode to No, that may fix it

Comment: Thanks. It is not inserting an empty record into the table. But It is still displaying an empty record on subform. Is there any way not to display on subform?

Comment: I just looked here - http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=89156 it suggests to turn off "Allow Additions" in Form Properties -- I've never done it though, I just ignore it.  I'd be interested to know what the solution is

Comment: I have tried setting up "Allow Additions" to No. But it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: are you sure you don't have empty records in your table?
make sure the comboBoxes does not have any value in "Control Source" if you have it, that might be a reason why you are creating empty records when you select a value.

Comment: Yes, you are right Krish. I had a value in "Control Source" which was causing the issue. Thanks.